# What is better practice: to store a string or use relations?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Well, I have to choose for myself what practice would be better to use. I try to explain what I mean. For example, I have table `Songs`:

```
Id | Name | Artist | Year
---+------+--------+-------
1  | Ad   | Bad    | 2015
2  | Sad  | ads    | 2011
3  | Wad  | Had    | 2012
```

And also, I want to implement table `Playlists`. And I don't exactly know, what practice would be better.

Approach #1 - use string to store Songs IDs

`Playlists` table:

```
Id | Name | Songs
---+------+------------------------
1  | Main | 1,2    
2  | GYM  | 4,6,7,8,53,65,76878,78,    
3  | Rock | 121,434,655,6767,78
```

So, to get songs that the some playlist stores, I will parse it every time I'm yielding a list from DB.

Approach #2 - use many-to-many relations strategy

`Playlists` table:

```
Id | Name 
---+------
1  | Main 
2  | GYM 
3  | Rock
```

`PlaylistSongs` table:

```
Id | PlaylistId | SongId
---+------------+---------
1  |      1     |    1
2  |      1     |    2    
4  |      1     |  344 
5  |      1     |   45
6  |      1     |   57
```

Approach #3 - Your advice

If you know better practice, feel free to share it with me :)

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Definitely use a many-to-many table, but it only needs to have the song and playlist ids it doesn't need it's own id, unless you want to be able to associate the same song with the same playlist more than once.

Comment: Absolutely option two. Option one is more like text describing data. It's not relational data. To illustrate, imagine trying to write queries that tried to search playlists for certain songs or join tables together. It would be really ugly with option 1 but easy with option 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PlaylistSongs` -- a many-to-many relationship -- is the correct way to store the data. Here are some reasons:

- A column in a SQL table should contain one value, not a multiplicity of values.
- Songs are shared among different play lists. They are their own entity. There is also additional information you want about each song (say when it was released, its genre, and so on).
- Numbers should not be stored as strings in a relational database; they should be stored as some numeric type.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared between tables.
- SQL has (in general) pretty bad parsing functions for strings.
- SQL can optimize data stored in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

Surely, a many to many relationship required as the playlist table clearly doesnt have atomic values rather a cluster for same column as `PlaylistId` in this case. Generally, this is the best practice we follow to encounter data redundancy/duplicates/atomicity(the thumb rule as in this case to apply any normalization (splitting the tables)). Data Integrity constraint be ACID (ATOMICITY, CONSISTENCY, Isolation, Durability)

Answer (score 1):

Surely you will go for a man-to-many relationship scenario as you explained in approach # 2 by creating a PlaylistSongs table. This truly fits in as a relational database scenario in an RDBMS. Consider the benefits you get compared to your first approach in following scenarios.

1.) Data Consistency issues, for example, how if you want to delete a song from Songs table that is attached to an album. The first approach would not restrict you from doing that but in the second approach you can create foreign key relationships that would trigger error.

2.) Data Joins. For example, Using SQL you can use Join to get all the songs available in a given album, but in first approach you'll have to first do manual string manipulations first to extract out ids and then get out song records individually (both terrible for programming and hectic on machine)

3.) You have full SQL support at your end to query dozens of scenarios for reporting, for example use Count to get number of songs in a given album etc etc..

Thanks.